# group array of objects and get the count in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, count, aggregation, group

I am having an array of objects:

```
[
  {
    medicationDetails: {
      category: 'Asthma',
      subCategory: '',
      providedBy: 'Doctor'
    }
  },
  {
    medicationDetails: {
      category: 'Diabetes',
      subCategory: 'Oral',
      providedBy: 'Nurse'
    }
  },
  {
    medicationDetails: {
      category: 'Asthma',
      subCategory: ''
      providedBy: 'Doctor'
    }
  },
  {
    medicationDetails: {
      category: 'Diabetes',
      subCategory: 'Insulin',
      providedBy: 'Doctor'
    }
  }
]
```

Some medication will have sub-category and some doesn't.

Need to group based on 'category', 'sub-category' and 'providedBy' and get the count like this:

```
[
  {
    medicationDetails: [
     {
      name: 'Asthma',
      providedByDoctorCount: 2,
      providedByNurseCount: 0
     },
     {
      name: 'Oral',
      providedByDoctorCount: 0,
      providedByNurseCount: 1
     },
     {
      name: 'Insulin',
      providedByDoctorCount: 1,
      providedByNurseCount: 0
     }
    ]
  }
]
```

I was tried with $group and $count but not getting the expected result.
Need some valuable help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

somewhat similar to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76206953/group-multiple-fields-and-get-respective-counts-using-mongodb).
you can conditionally sum based on the value of the field when grouping

1. Create a `key` field based on `category` and `subCategory` values
2. Group by the key and add to `providedByDoctor` or `providedByNure` conditionally based on the value of `providedBy`
3. Group into a single `medicationDetails` array

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { 
   $project: {
      providedBy: "$medicationDetails.providedBy",
      key: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$medicationDetails.subCategory", "" ] }, "$medicationDetails.category", "$medicationDetails.subCategory" ] }
    } 
  },
  {
    $group: { 
      _id: "$key",
      providedByDoctor: { $sum: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$providedBy", "Doctor" ] }, 1, 0 ] } },
      providedByNurse: { $sum: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$providedBy", "Nurse" ] }, 1, 0 ] } } }
  },
  { $group: { _id: null, medicationDetails: { $push: { name: "$_id", providedByDoctorCount: "$providedByDoctor", providedByNurseCount: "$providedByNurse" } } } },
  { $unset: "_id" }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/su7P3K6HQfD)